# With sed or awk, how to replace all occurrences of string between quotes?

Tags: awk, sed

Given a file that looks like:

```
some text
no replace "text in quotes" no replace
more text
no replace "more text in quotes" no replace
even more text
no replace "even more text in quotes" no replace
etc
```

what `sed` or `awk` script would replace all the `e`s that are between quotes and only the `e`s between quotes such that something like the following is produced:

```
some text
no replace "t@#$xt in quot@#$s" no replace
more text
no replace "mor@#$ t@#$xt in quot@#$s" no replace
even more text
no replace "@#$v@#$n mor@#$ t@#$xt in quot@#$s" no replace
etc
```

There can be any number `e`s between the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {gsub(/e/,"@#$",$2)} 1' file
some text
no replace "t@#$xt in quot@#$s" no replace
more text
no replace "mor@#$ t@#$xt in quot@#$s" no replace
even more text
no replace "@#$v@#$n mor@#$ t@#$xt in quot@#$s" no replace
etc
```

Also consider multiple pairs of quotes on a line:

```
$ echo 'aebec"edeee"fegeh"eieje"kelem' |
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {gsub(/e/,"@#$",$2)} 1'
aebec"@#$d@#$@#$@#$"fegeh"eieje"kelem

$ echo 'aebec"edeee"fegeh"eieje"kelem' |
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/e/,"@#$",$i)} 1'
aebec"@#$d@#$@#$@#$"fegeh"@#$i@#$j@#$"kelem
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot there's some text on the same line that shouldn't be replaced. I've modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"e]*"[^"]*)*"[^"e]*)e/\1@#$/;ta' file
```

This regex looks from the start of line for a series of non-double quote characters, followed by a possible pair of double quotes with no `e`'s within them, followed by another possibile series of non-double quote characters, followed by a double quote and a possible series of non-double quotes. If the next pattern is an `e` it replaces the pattern by the `\1` (which is everything up until the `e`) and `@#$`. If the substitution is successful i.e. `ta`, then the process is repeated until no further substitutions occur.

N.B. This caters for lines with multiple pairs of double quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':cycle
s/^\(\([^"]*\("[^"]*"\)*\)*"[^"]*\)e/\1@#$/
t cycle' YourFile
```

- Posix version
- front last till first `e`
- change also any `e` that will be in an *unclosed* quoted string (at the end thus and failed in next line if that could happend (Not present in your sample)